# Using defaultdict to append a list from an .xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, defaultdict

I'm trying to take an excel file with two fields, ID and xy coordinates and create a dictionary so that each ID is a key to all of the xy coordinate values.

for example, the excel file looks like this:
[1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2agc.png

but there are more than 900 oID values

I want the final format to be something like, 
[('0',[-121.129247,37.037939,-121.129247,37.037939,-121.056516,36.997779]),
('1',[all, the, coordinates,with,oID,of,1]),('2'[all,the,coordinate,with,oID,of,2]etc.)]

I am trying to use a for statement to iterate through the excel sheet to populate a list with the first 200 rows, and then putting that into a default dict.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('simpleCoordinate.xlsx')
sheet=wb['Sheet1']

from collections import defaultdict

CoordDict = defaultdict(list)
for i in range (1,201,1):
    coordinate_list=[(sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value, sheet.cell(row=i,     column=2).value)]

for oID, xy in coordinate_list:
   CoordDict[oID].append(xy)

print(list(CoordDict.items()))
```

which returns:

```
[(11, ['-121.177487,35.49885'])]
```

Only the 200th line of the excel sheet, rather than the whole thing.. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, is it something with the for statement? Am I thinking about this in the wrong way? I'm a total newbie to python any advice would be helpful!

Comment: You are overwriting coordinate_list 200 times.

Comment: It seems to me that an intermediate list is not necessary at all. You should be able to write the values straight to the `CoordDict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting `coordinate_list`  200 times. Instead, create it, then append to it with the `+=` operator.

```
wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('simpleCoordinate.xlsx')
sheet=wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

from collections import defaultdict

coordinate_list = list()
for i in range (1,201,1):
    coordinate_list += [(sheet.cell(row=i,column=1).value, sheet.cell(row=i,     column=2).value)]

coord_dict = defaultdict(list)
for oid, xy in coordinate_list:
    coord_dict[oid] = xy

print(list(coord_dict.items()))
```

Comment: This worked- it also ended up working when I just put the second for statement within the first.

Comment: That's because you were creating coordinate list with a length of 1...200 times. In other words, each time you created a one item list, then append that one item to `CoordDict` then overwrite the list again in the next outer loop. Very inefficient.

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, please accept my answer since you say it is correct.